# SQL query improvement

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have this query which takes 20 seconds to run...

```
SELECT books.id, books.title, books.slug, books.source_id, books.thumb_url 
FROM books, book_cat 
WHERE books.id = book_cat.book_id AND book_cat.cat_id = 158 
ORDER BY books.id DESC LIMIT 50
```

`book_cat` is a join table between `book` and `book_cats`

There are 39k rows in `book_cat` for `cat_id` = 158

Any suggestions?

-- update

All PKs, FKs, indexes (including combined indexes on book_cat) are in place.

BIGINT yes I know, I'm expecting A LOT of books, tempted to change to INT.

The UNIQUE key, that's a candidate for PK

```
CREATE TABLE book_cat (
    book_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    cat_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(book_id, cat_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_book_cat_1 FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_book_cat_2 FOREIGN KEY (cat_id) REFERENCES book_cats (id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: What indexes do you have in the tables? Columns used for foreign keys and for searching should ideally be indexed to make your queries as efficient and fast as possible.

Comment: What is the data type of cat_id?

Comment: A combined index on (book_id, cat_id) of the `book_cats` table could help

Comment: Please see the update, indexes are automatically put in place for FKs and UNIQUE keys (that gives the combined index - MySQL 5.6.15), cat_id type just a SMALLINT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'm going to rewrite your query with table aliases and proper `join` syntax:

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, b.slug, b.source_id, b.thumb_url 
FROM books JOIN
     book_cat bc
     ON b.id = bc.book_id
WHERE bc.cat_id = 158 
ORDER BY b.id DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

To optimize this query, be sure that you have an index on `book_cat(book_id, cat_id)` and on `books(id)`.  The following equivalent version of the query might produce the best plan:

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, b.slug, b.source_id, b.thumb_url 
FROM books
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM book_cat bc WHERE b.id = bc.book_id AND bc.cat_id = 158)
ORDER BY b.id DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

This version emphasis that the `order by` can use the index and that the search for the categories should use the index.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, please see the update to the question, all the indexes are in place. The rewrite #1 above still takes 20 seconds, however the rewrite using EXISTS 0.015 seconds! Any analogy for this huge difference?

Comment: @user2723025 . . . You would have to look at the execution plans to understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The usual culprit in cases like this not having an index with appropriate values in it.  I would suggest an index on book_cat with both book_id and cat_id in it.  The order probably doesn't matter but which ever is more exclusive I'd use first.

You might try using [mySQL's EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) statement to see what info it will give you.  Make sure it's using the expected index, or create an index and then try it again.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure your tables are defined correctly. `books.id` should be defined as a primary key. An index should exist on `book_cat.book_id` and `book_cat.catid`, as they seem to be foreign keys to other tables.

If that is done, then the following SQL should be pretty fast for the amount of records you are dealing with.

```
SELECT books.id, books.title, books.slug, books.source_id, books.thumb_url 
FROM books JOIN book_cat ON books.id = book_cat.book_id
WHERE book_cat.cat_id = 158 
ORDER BY books.id DESC LIMIT 50
```

Comment: thanks, dealing with 39k records *for* category id 158, the total record count in book_cat join table is 4.7m, that must contribute to the execution time...